# Save not Serializable Collection to the file

Tags: java, serialization, collections, persist

I have Collection with objects which I want to persist to the file:

```
private List< TestPart > testParts;
```

Class TestPart is extending Abstract class and two interfaces.
Is it possible to write that kind of collection to the file?
I tried to use jaxb/kryo - without effect.

Class TestPart is not implementing Serializable interface and I can't change it.

I should also mention that class TestPart has a references to the other not serializable classes.

Any ideas how to save data like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could parse the collections into XML or json

Comment: Mark the `List<TestPart>` as `transient` and modify the `writeObject` and `readObject` to perform a manual serialization of this field and its contents, similar for `readObject` method and the retrieval of the serialized content.

Comment: you want to save an object that is not serializable , you can't .
how can you expect from a collection of non-serializable to be serialize.?

Comment: You should check out [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I should also mention that class TestPart has a references to the other not serializable classes. Post updated.

Comment: I checked XStream  but I'm getting ConversionException